# Count Each String In A List with One Character Mismatch

Tags: python, string, dataframe

I have a list of strings:

```
my_list = 'AAA AAA BBB BBB DDD DDD DDA'.split()
my_list

['AAA', 'AAA', 'BBB', 'BBB', 'DDD', 'DDD', 'DDA']
```

I need to count every element appearing in the list. However, if two strings have one mismatch, we would count them as the same string and then count.

I mostly use the following script to count.

```
my_list.count('AAA')
```

However, not sure about how to implement the mismatch part. I am thinking to run two `for loops`, compare two strings and then increment the count. It would be O(n^2).

***Desired Output***

```
AAA 2
BBB 2
DDD 3
DDA 3
```

What would be the ideal way of getting the desired output? Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What if there is also "DAA" which is one mistake away from "DDA" and "AAA"?

Comment: I would start with a `collections.Counter()` on your base list of words for sure. That should reduce the remaining tests that I fear will break down in some ugly On2 calculations

Comment: Google "edit distance" to find algorithms for calculating the number of differences between strings.

Comment: Hi @MichaelButscher, you are right. Then their count would be increased.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with an unoptimized method to test if two words are "close".  You might lookup or import a real library that did "Levenshtein distance" rather than my half baked approach:

```py
def is_close_enough(word1, word2):    # Levenshtein Distance == 1 ?
    if word1 == word2:
        return True

    if len(word1) != len(word2):
        return False

    return sum(c1==c2 for c1, c2 in zip(word1, word2)) >= len(word1) -1

print(is_close_enough("dog", "bog"))
print(is_close_enough("dog", "bot"))
print(is_close_enough("dog", "cat"))
print(is_close_enough("dog", "dogo"))
```

That should give you:

```
True
False
False
False
```

Now let's try that in conjunction with your base list of words.

```py
import collections

def is_close_enough(word1, word2):    # Levenshtein Distance == 1 ?
    if word1 == word2:
        return True

    if len(word1) != len(word2):
        return False

    return sum(c1==c2 for c1, c2 in zip(word1, word2)) >= len(word1) -1

my_list = 'AAA AAA BBB BBB DDD DDD DDA'.split()
my_list_counted = collections.Counter(my_list)

print({
    word1: sum(
        count2
        for word2, count2
        in my_list_counted.items()
        if is_close_enough(word1, word2)
    )
    for word1
    in my_list_counted
})
```

That should give you:

```
{'AAA': 2, 'BBB': 2, 'DDD': 3, 'DDA': 3}
```

**Addendum:**

If you had a specific list of interesting words to find rather than all matches you would iterate through it instead:

```py
import collections

def is_close_enough(word1, word2):    # Levenshtein Distance == 1 ?
    if word1 == word2:
        return True

    if len(word1) != len(word2):
        return False

    return sum(c1==c2 for c1, c2 in zip(word1, word2)) >= len(word1) -1

my_interesting_words = ["AAA", "DDA"]
my_list = 'AAA AAA BBB BBB DDD DDD DDA'.split()
my_list_counted = collections.Counter(my_list)

print({
    word1: sum(
        count2
        for word2, count2
        in my_list_counted.items()
        if is_close_enough(word1, word2)
    )
    for word1
    in my_interesting_words
})
```

Comment: Hi @JonSG, thank you for your help. Appreciate. Here, we counted each element from a list itself. What if, we want to count the occurrence of each element of a smaller list from a longer list (including mismatch). I mean how many times an element from a smaller happens in a longer list.

Comment: Thank you for the update @JonSG. Such a great learning experience!